# How many possible policies in a Markov Decision Process?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, decision-problem, markov-chains

If a policy yields an action for a state, how come a 3-state MDP with 2 possible actions, i.e. $S = \{Hot, Mild, Cold\}$,  $A = \{East, West\}$, has **8** possible policies? Isn't it 6 if there are 2 possible action for every state?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are a bit confused by the notion of *MDP policy*. There's a detailed discussion with lots of examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260775/what-does-exactly-the-policy-mean-reinforcement-learning/46265324).

A policy is any possible strategy in a given environment. Example: "go $East$ in any state" is a valid strategy in your MDP (though maybe not optimal), as well as "go $West$ in any state".

So there are 3 states and 2 possible actions per each, hence $|A|^{|S|} = 2^3 = 8$ possible strategies: $EEE$, $EEW$, ..., $WWW$.